# System.ArgumentNullException error with MonoDevelop compiling a c# code

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I have another simple question. I have a C# program written as a .cs file. MonoDevelop (improved by Xamarin) managed to build this project. However, when I try to run it, I get the error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: s
  at System.Double.Parse (System.String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider)[0x00012] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono- 2.10.9/mcs/class/corlib/System/Double.cs:229
  at System.Double.Parse (System.String s) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.9/mcs/class/corlib/System/Double.cs:200
  at SampleNamespace.SampleClass.Main () [0x00049] in /Users/ninakuklisova/ThoughtWorks/Sales Taxes with inputs.cs:42
```

which points to the following line of the code:

```
values[ItemNumber,2] = Double.Parse(quant);
```

What I find mysterious is that there is no
    /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.9/mcs/class/corlib/System/ 
folder on my Mac, and when I compiled this code on online compilers, all went well. Do you know what could be wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That folder probably existed on the machine of whoever compiled mono.
2. Check to see if `quant` is null.

Comment: ... or use Double.TryParse

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response, guys! I'm still puzzled -  quant is not null, and Double.TryParse does not seem to work either. Do you have more ideas?

Comment: How doesn't it work? What is actually in `quant`? Please update your question, and I might be able to update my answer

Comment: It seems like I solved the problem: it didn't want to work with array elements in a random order; when I renamed values[ItemNumber,2] = Double.Parse(quant); as values[ItemNumber,1] = Double.Parse(quant); and the next element mentioned, [ItemNumber,1], as [ItemNumber,2], I didn't receive any more error messages.

But my brain wouldn't have turned on without your help. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, although I'm not entirely sure I understand what the issue was. The exception you showed is definitely from Double.Parse, so... Well, good that it's resolved anyway!

Comment: The exception from Double.Parse occurred at the line where I told it to parse the confusing element :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was that simple: just don't mention column 2 before column 1. I guess most people won't do it anyways.